# Ignore database column with Load Data SQL?

Tags: php, sql

I'm loading data into my database from a CSV file using LOAD DATA as follows:

> LOAD DATA INFILE '$filelocation' INTO TABLE wl_daily FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' IGNORE 1 LINES

The issue I have is that in my database, the first column is called ID, whereas the first column in my csv files is called Month.

How do I go about telling LOAD DATA to load the data from each row into the database starting at the month field?

Answer (score 0):

Please see the LOAD DATA Syntax on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html.

You can add a list of columns to your query where to add the read data like:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filelocation' 
INTO TABLE wl_daily FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(month, columnToAddSecondValue, columnToAddThirdValue, ...)
```

If you don't want to save a value read from the file assign it to a var that you ignore.

```
LOAD DATA INFILE '$filelocation' 
INTO TABLE wl_daily FIELDS TERMINATED BY ';' 
IGNORE 1 LINES
(@ignore, month, columnToAddSecondValue, columnToAddThirdValue, ...)
```

Comment: Is it possible just to tell it to ignore the first column, rather than having to list all the columns out?  I knew you could add the columns in, however the csv has a lot and it would be neater to not list them all out.

Comment: If your first column were a fixed string or has a fixed string in it, you could try to use `LINES STARTING BY `.